# Importing shapefile to PostGIS using Python and ogr

Tags: python, postgis, shapefile, ogr, import

I just export a PostGIS Table to shp using [this tips](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16737/how-to-convert-postgis-table-to-shapefile-in-python) but I'm not able to import a shp to PostGIS using the same library(ogr). Any idea?

Comment: Do you really need to use python to do it, or are you just trying to import the file? I fall you need to do is import the file then use ogr2ogr on the command line     
`ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:”dbname=DBNAME host=localhost" file.shp -nln TABLENAME`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In pure Python, without using the subprocess module (os.system is deprecated) to call `ogr2ogr` or `shp2pgsql`, for example):

#### 1) with ogr

- [Append a shapefile to a postgis table using the GDAL/OGR Python interface](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2011-July/029304.html)

#### 2) with ogr and  [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/) from the book [Python Geospatial Development](http://www.packtpub.com/python-geospatial-development-second-edition/book) (Eric Westra), Chapter 7, p.219

```
import os.path  
import psycopg2
import osgeo.ogr  
connection = psycopg2.connect("dbname=... user=...")  
cursor = connection.cursor()  
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM countries")  
srcFile = os.path.join("DISTAL-data", "TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3","TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp")  
shapefile = osgeo.ogr.Open(srcFile)    
layer = shapefile.GetLayer(0)    
for i in range(layer.GetFeatureCount()):  
    feature = layer.GetFeature(i)  
    name = feature.GetField("NAME").decode("Latin-1")  
    wkt = feature.GetGeometryRef().ExportToWkt()  
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO countries (name,outline) " +"VALUES (%s, ST_GeometryFromText(%s, " +"4326))", (name.encode("utf8"), wkt))  

connection.commit()
```

#### 3) with [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/) only

- [How to save a newly created shapefile in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29059/how-to-save-a-newly-created-shapefile-in-postgis)

#### 4) with [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/) and other spatial libraries

- [shp-postgis-schema](https://github.com/nathancahill/shp-postgis-schema) with [pyshp (shapefile)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshp/1.2.0)
- [shapefile_importer.py](https://gist.github.com/patmisch/2650602), also with pyshp

Comment: Option 3 does not actually have an answer to the question.