# Get srid from a shapefile using ogr

Tags: python, gdal, osgeo, psycopg2

I'm writing a script to import shp to postgis,
using python, osgeo and psycopg2
( see my previous question: 
[Import shp to Postgis using Python and ogr](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90085/import-shp-to-postgis-using-python-and-ogr) )

I'd know if there is a way to get by osgeo library the SRID (for example 4326) of the shp.

So I can confirm the SRID or transform it using script directly.

Comment: franco, are you aware that ogr includes scripts ([ogr2ogr](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=ogr_cheatsheet) in particular) that do this already, and that you don't need python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the [Python GDAL/OGR Cookbook 1.0 documentation](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/projection.html#get-projection) and you'll have the answers to all your questions:

```
    from osgeo import ogr
    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
    shape = driver.Open('my.shp')
    layer= shape.GetLayer()
    # the crs
    crs = layer.GetSpatialRef()
```

and you can also create a projection file if the shapefile does not have one or reproject the shapefile with `osgeo.osr`

Answer (score 3):

`ogrinfo layer.shp layer -so` will give you general information about the shapefile.

Answer (score 1):

> **for display crs finally you can use crs.proj4**

```
from osgeo import ogr
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
shape = driver.Open('my.shp')
layer= shape.GetLayer()
# the crs
```

### crs = layer.GetSpatialRef()

> > > crs.proj4()

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Python, gdalsrsinfo (which you probalby have installed if you have ogrinfo) will also work to display the SRS from a shapefile:

```
gdalsrsinfo shapefile.shp
```

Answer (score 0):

You could user [ogrinfo](https://gdal.org/programs/ogrinfo.html)

```
ogrinfo -so -al shapefile.shp
```

`-so` : Summary Only: suppress listing of individual features and show only summary information like projection, schema, feature count and extents.

`-al` : List all features of all layers (used instead of having to give layer names as arguments).