# Import shapefile to PostGIS using Python and OGR?

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, postgresql

I am not able to import a shapefile to PostGIS using the same library (OGR). I am using below link but it gives me error.
[Import shp to Postgis using Python and ogr](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90085/import-shp-to-postgis-using-python-and-ogr)

**Error:**

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/n/.qgis2/python/plugins\Importtool\Import_tool.py", line 223, in select_output_file_5

```
layer = shapefile.GetLayer(0)
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetLayer'

Comment: double check that you got the filename correct for your shapefile. osgeo.ogr.Open(srcFile) returns None if it can't find or open the file

Comment: srcFile = os.path.join("DISTAL-data", "TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3","C:\Users\n\Downloads\TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3\TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp")  
  shapefile = osgeo.ogr.Open(srcFile)    
  layer = shapefile.GetLayer(0)    
  for i in range(layer.GetFeatureCount()):  
   feature = layer.GetFeature(i)  
   name = feature.GetField("NAME").decode("Latin-1")  
   wkt = feature.GetGeometryRef().ExportToWkt()  
   cur.execute("INSERT INTO countries (name,outline) " +"VALUES (%s, ST_GeometryFromText(%s, " +"4326))", (name.encode("utf8"), wkt))
   conn.commit()

Answer (score 3):

the problem is this line...

```
srcFile = os.path.join("DISTAL-data", "TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3","C:\Users\n\Downloads\TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3\TM_WORLD_BORDE‌​RS-0.3.shp")
```

os.path.join() will create this file path (under windows)

\DISTAL-data\TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3\C:\Users\n\Downloads\TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3\TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp

which probably isn't a valid path. Just replace it with

```
srcFile = 'C:\Users\n\Downloads\TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3\TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp'
```

and it should work.